# Drupal 7 single language views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a website which is developed in three languages. I created a taxonomy vocabulary (product category), which is output from the views. Inside the term gallery thumbnail image products. So, how do single language for the gallery to not have to add three times the same image for multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

you could set it to language neutral and allow both content in the selected language and language neutral to be shown

Comment: Probably a good answer, but please take some care about editing. Capitals and dots exists for better readability, so please use them, for example :)

Comment: I added content with neutral language. In the settings views I chose filter `No language`, but the content is only visible to the default language. How to fix it?

Comment: Dear Pearson, What do you mean with the default language?
If it is set to language neutral, there is no default language? :)